# Retrieving information from java scroll list

Tags: java, list, scroll, jlist

I was wondering how I were to do if I wanted to retrieve the chosen answer from a java scroll list (JScrollPane), and then display it in a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog? For example I would use gettext() if I wanted to get it from a textarea/box, but how do I retrieve the answer from a java scroll list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `getSelectedValuesList()` which returns a list of all selected items.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList%28%29)

Comment: Yeah that is what I was looking for! Thanks alot! Works now!